# questions on free and bound variables

Tags: variables, scope, free

I've been reading through Structures And Interpretations of Computer Programs  and have come to a confusing point the book is trying to explain about free and bound variables. I have read many explanations on this site about this concept but none seem to do it for me. Here is the text explaining bound and free variables:

*the book uses the programming language Lisp (Scheme)

"A formal procedure has a very special role in the procedure definition in that it doesn't matter what name the formal parameter has. Such a name is called a bound variable."

My first question is why is it important that it doesn't matter what name the formal parameter has?

" We say that the procedure definition *binds* its formal parameters. The meaning of a procedure definition is unchanged if a bound variable is consistently renamed throughout the definition."

ok, the use of the word *binds* here means absolutely nothing to me. More importantly, what are some examples of a bound variable being renamed throughout a definition? Every procedure I've created throughout the book has never talked about changing the names of formal parameters of a procedure definition *within* that procedure definition. From what I understand, you set the formal parameters at the beginning of the procedure definition and that is that.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we defined a procedure `f`:

```
def f(x):
    print(x + z)
```

One can describe it as follows: `f` takes a parameter `x`, and prints the result when `x` is added with the global variable `z`.

Now suppose we had renamed `x` to `y` throughout the definition:

```
def f(y):
    print(y + z)
```

It's clear that this function does the exact same thing as it did before. This is because the name `x` in the initial definition, or `y` in this definition, occurs "bound" in `f`. It doesn't matter whether it's named `x` or `y`.

In contrast, if we defined `f` as follows:

```
def f(x):
    print(x + w)
```

Now this definition of `f` is different: instead of adding its parameter with `z`, it adds it with `w`. It matters that we renamed `z` to `w`, because the occurrence of `z` in the function body was "free", not "bound".